# why can't I see keyvault secrets in portal, but can access them programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azureportal

**The access**

This is the service principal keyvault access policy:
[image]

Service Principal:
[image]

Service admin / Portal user:
[image]

**Why can't I see the secrets, although I can access them programmatically?**

[image]

The access policy
[image]
[image]

Comment: Programmatically means, from runbook ?

Comment: you are talking about "service principal". Do you mean your user by this or is that an actual AAD SPN?

Comment: I can access the keyvault and read secrets with python by using azure-keyvault and azure-secrets modules. But I can‘t see them from within the portal. I meant AAD SP

Comment: What are the access policies assigned to the user account accessing the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From your last screenshot, I observed that you created access policy **only for service principal** that allows it to access secrets programmatically.

To fix your issue, you need to create new access policy by selecting your **user account** under `Principal` tab like below:

[image]

Make sure to assign **list secret** permissions to your user account and click on **`Create`** like below:

[image]

After creating access policy, the user account will appear under **`USER`** like below:

[image]

When I signed in with that user account, I'm able to access **secrets** successfully like below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can switch permission model to **Azure role-based access control** if you prefer to accessing with RBAC roles like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using SPN to access the keyvault programmatically and using user credential to view the secrets from the portal?

From the snapshots, I can see that the keyvault is set to Access policy authorization model. This means the roles on RBAC will not affect the reading/writing of contents of the Keyvault.
You need to assign an access policy to the user or SPN to allow this.

I can see that there is an access policy for your SPN which is why you can read the keyvault contents programmatically using this SPN. However, the user only has a service administrator RBAC role. But since Access policies don't allow RBAC roles to  access the contents, you cannot see the keyvault contents on the portal.

Keyvault has 2 authorization models, RBAC and Access policies. You can read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-migration). Access policy is the older model and doesn't allow granular access to a single key/secret. RBAC is the newer model launched in 2021 which allows you to set roles at the individual entity level to segregate access to each key, secret.